# Comparing values in a variable to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in Python that has the name of the car, the colour and the carcount to how many is currently in stock (below is a example of a few):

```
cardict = {
    'Ferrari': {'Colour': 'Red', 'Carcount': 0},
    'Lambo': {'Colour': 'Yellow', 'Carcount': 0},
    'Mustang': {'Colour': 'Black', 'Carcont': 0},
}
```

I have a variable called `stock` which stores the names of many different car models. If a car model like `'Ferrari'` is found in the variable, I wish it to compare the variable to the dictionary, If `'Ferrari'` is found in the variable, let's say 3 times, I wish the count in the dictionary to change from `0` to `3` and I'm looking for a way I can achieve this.

**Updated Edit:**

The name of the cars come from a text file with hundreds of different cars, and I have used 'with open' to open the text file and then if the car.startswith "Ferrari" to make that into a variable. I used int(car[15:]) to get rid of the other text I didn't need and just display the car name which was put into a variable 'stock'.

Also, when I print to the console the 'count' value: **'{'Carcount': 0}'** is printed.

```
for c in cardict: 
    print(cardict[c])
```

Output:

```
 '{'Carcount': 0}'
```

Is there a way I can just print the value '0' to the console instead of printing the {'count': } part?

Eg:

```
0
2
```

Comment: What is `stock`? A list, string, dict, ...? Also you have some curly quotes in your code.

Comment: Hello, may I know how the car names are being represented in the variable "stock"? Is it in a list?

Comment: 'Stock' is the variable in which many different car models are stored, such as; ferrari, ford, mustang, lambo. The models such as 'ferrari' can be appearing more than once, such as 3 times. So when the variable name 'stock' is printed, the output could is something like this:                          ferrari                                                                                           ferrari                                                                                           ford                                                                                              etc

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Comment: The answer to your followup question is to change the line of code inside your for loop to this: `print(cardict[c]["Carcount"])`

Comment: Also I updated my answer, let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
stock = ["Ferrari", "Lambo", "Ferrari"]

for carname in cardict.keys():
    cardict[carname]['Carcount'] = stock.count(carname)
```

**Edit**: I think I understand your edit now. The variable `stock` is holding a single car name rather than a list of car names. In that case, here's my updated code:

```
stock = "Ferrari"
cardict[stock]['Carcount'] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to specify that the name of the cars come from a text file with hundreds of different cars, and I have used 'with open' to open the text file and then if the car.startswith "Ferrari" to make that into a variable. I used int(car[15:]) to get rid of the other text I didn't need and just display the car name which was put into a variable 'stock'.

Comment: @N2This Add that any other relevant information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that the items are stored in a variable (i.e. a List), here is a possible solution:

```
# An example of a stock list you might have
carlist = ["Ferrari", "Ferrari", "Ferrari", "Lambo", "Lambo", "Mustang"]

for car in carlist:
    if car in cardict:
        cardict[car]['Carcount'] += 1
print(cardict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
stock = ['ferrari', 'ford', 'ferrari', 'mustang', 'lambo', 'mustang', 'ferrari', 'ford', 'ford']

cardict = {m: {k: v if k=='Colour' else stock.count(m.lower()) for k, v in n.items()} for m, n in cardict.items()}
```

Yields:

```
{'Ferrari': {'Colour': 'Red', 'Carcount': 3}, 'Lambo': {'Colour': 'Yellow', 'Carcount': 1}, 'Mustang': {'Colour': 'Black', 'Carcont': 2}}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to print to the console just the 'count' value but instead '{'Carcount': 0}' is printed to the console when I use:  for c in cardict:                                                                                 
                          print(cardict[c])                                                     Is there a way I can just print the value '0' to the console instead of printing the {'count': } part?